# Can a Macbook Pro Output Video through the 3.5mm Audio Port?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, audio, video, video-adapter

I have a Macbook Pro mid 2014 running OS X El Capitan and I also have a 3.5mm audio jack to component plug. I want to display my computer screen on my TV (which has component input) but all I have is the 3.5mm audio jack to component. I don't want to buy another cable and I don't want to by an Apple TV. **So, can the Macbook Pro output video (I don't care what quality) through the 3.5mm audio jack port or is there any way to configure it so I can do this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  It's an ***audio port*** not an *audio/video* port.

[image]

Per the Apple Support site: [Mac Basics: Ports on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201736)

[image]

---

HDMI and the Thunderbolt Ports will carry both digital video with audio, but your analog audio port (denoted by the headphone icon) will only carry audio.

Your option here is to get an HDMI to Composite adapter that will convert the digital video/audio signals to analog composite signals.  There are different makes/manufacturers.  You should pick one with good ratings and that is not too expensive.

[image]

Comment: I actually found HDMI to HDMI but still was just wondering. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No. This is an analog port. Not sure the max channels it offers, but most audio uses two to three. Analog video needs way more, hence the pins on a VGA plug. We're in the days of digital, however. HDMI,Thunderbolt, USB-C, etc...

Comment: How does this improve on the existing answer which answers the question in much more detail